# Increase the file size limit in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a sql file `480,396kb`. I could not import the file in my `phpmyadmin` in this memory limit

is (Max: `128MiB`) only. When I import the sql file it shows the error

> You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to
>   documentation for a workaround for this limit.

I changed the memory limit in `php.ini` file  both

`upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` also.

Comment: also increase  max execution time limit.

Comment: This [FAQ entry](https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/QA_4_0/faq.html?highlight=import%20size#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems) from phpMyAdmin documentation on importing big dump files might come handy.

Answer (score 6):

Importing a large file from the command line is simple:

```
#mysql -p... -u... -h... database_name < file.sql
```

OR

You can use this plugins

[Get from Here](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.zip)

Answer (score 3):

restart the connection of your apache.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change max_file_uploads,
did you see maxfilesize to upload in phpmyadmin,if you change all in php.ini then it must update,

also restart apache

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the mysql command line tool for importing a database. This way you don't have the memory limit problem and the import is 100x faster.

Comment: How to use that and where please tel....

Comment: Agreed with Ishu. Learnt nothing from this answer, or the command line answer by Napster.